# how to record in which direction the swipe was performed? UNITY

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wanted to make that when you swipe to the left you apply a left force and when you swipe to the right you apply a right force.

this is how I imagine the code would be:

```
private Vector2 direction;

void Update()
{
    swipeDirection();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb2D.AddForce(direction);
}

void swipeDirection()
{
    if (swipe to the left)
    {
        direction = new Vector2(-10, 0);
    }
    else if (swipe to the right)
    {
        direction = new Vector2(10, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: With mouse or touch input?

Comment: Seems needs to be with touch, but just to confirm

Comment: whit touch input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ApplyForceOnSwipe: MonoBehaviour {
    Vector3 touchInitPos;
    Vector3 touchEndPos;
    bool applyForce = false;
    Vector3 forceDir;

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
            touchInitPos = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
        }
        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended) {
            touchEndPos = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            forceDir = (touchEndPos - touchInitPos).normalized;
            applyForce = true;
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        if (applyForce) {
            rb2D.AddForce(forceDir);
            applyForce = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Used a boolean to avoid applying the force multiple times and apply it only once per swipe.
Not debuggued. Hope it might work or inspire you :)

Comment: I don't know why, but when I scroll the player moves extremely slowly.
when you wrote: forceDir = (touchEndPos - touchInitPos) .normalize; do you mean .normalized or .Normalize()?

Comment: you can increase the force for faster movement I guess. I meant [Vector3.normalized](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-normalized.html). Corrected in the question (code is no not debugged) to get the swipe direction

Comment: to increate the force you can increase the addforce vector multiplying the normalized vector with magnitude 1 by a float called `power` maybe, with the value of your desired impusle force: `rb2D.AddForce(forceDir * power);`